# Images lazy loading with Intersection Observer API issue

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

everyone.

I've got gallery of 1609 images and I'm trying to configure images lazy loading with Intersection observer API and stuck with the problem, that no matter what, I've got all of them to be uploaded instantly, meaning that lazy loading doesn't work. Here's full code listing for the simple testing page below:

```
    <?php 

    $listOfFolders = scandir(__DIR__);
    $images = [];


    foreach ($listOfFolders as $folder) {
        if($folder == "." || $folder == ".." || $folder == "index.php")
        {
            continue;
        } else {
            $innerFolders = scandir("./".$folder);
            foreach ($innerFolders as $innerFolder) {
                if($innerFolder == "." || $innerFolder == ".." || $innerFolder == "index.php")
                {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    $imagesList = scandir('./'.$folder.'/'.$innerFolder);
                    foreach ($imagesList as $image) {
                        if($image == "." || $image == ".." || $image == "index.php"){
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            array_push($images, ($folder.'/'.$innerFolder.'/'.$image));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lazy Loading testing</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



        <style type="text/css">

            .images-wrapper
            {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            }

            .images-wrapper .image-wrapper
            {
                max-width: 25%;
                width: 100%;
                margin-bottom: 15px;
            }

            .images-wrapper .image-wrapper img
            {
                max-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100px;
                background-color: #000;
            }
        </style>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="images-wrapper">
                    <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <img data-src="<?php echo './'.$image; ?>">
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
                let options = {
                    root: null,
                    rootMargin: "0px 0px -150px 0px",
                    threshold: 1.0
                }

                let observer = new IntersectionObserver(
                    (entries, self) => {
                        entries.forEach(entry => {
                            console.log(entry.isIntersecting);
                            if(entry.isIntersecting){
                                preloadImage(entry.target);
                                self.unobserve(entry.target);
                            }
                        });
                    }, options);

                let imgs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-src]');
                imgs.forEach(img => {
                    observer.observe(img);
                });

                function preloadImage(img)
                {
                    let imgDataSrcAttr = img.getAttribute('data-src');
                    img.setAttribute("src", imgDataSrcAttr);
                }
            </script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

First thing I checked was "isIntersecting" property and for some reason, all 1609 images returns "true" while only about 20-30 of them should have this value.

Run out of ideas why it behaves this way. Any hint please?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I've found the source of problem: **display:flex** for parent container.

My guess is that as this CSS property initially lines up all images within one row and JS consider all images to be in designated rectangle to do images loading. It seems that use of **flex-wrap: wrap** doesn't change anything - just makes images look like there were splitted in rows - and for JS they're still lined up in on row within observed rectange